# Web workers HTMLElement not defined

Tags: reactjs, web-worker, vite, comlink

I am using Web Workers in React with [Comlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comlink) and Vite.

---

It's my first time using web workers.

I am trying to get the web worker just to add two numbers together. When clicking the button, I am getting this error. If anyone has a work around or fix for this it will be greatly appreciated.

> overlay.ts:118 Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined at overlay.ts:118:35 (anonymous) @ overlay.ts:118

`vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
      ...rest
      worker: {
        plugins: [react()],
      },
})
```

`utils.tsx`

```
export const addNumbers = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}
```

`main.tsx`

```
          <button
            onClick={async () => {
              const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url), {
                type: 'module',
              })

              const instance = wrap<import('./worker').RunAddNumbers>(worker)
              await instance.addNumbers(a, b)
            }}
          >
            Download
          </button>
```

`worker.ts`

```
import { expose } from 'comlink'

import { addNumbers } from './utils'

const worker = {
  addNumbers,
}

export type RunAddNumbers = typeof worker

expose(worker)
```

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers is where i got `new URL('./worker.tsx', import.meta.url)` from

Comment: That has `new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url)`, not 'worker.tsx`. TSX files are TypeScript files with JSX abilities, something I doubt you'd need in a Web Worker. Also, I don't know how Vite or Comlink work, but importing a web worker directly from a TypeScript file, without transpilation to JavaScript, is unlikely to work.

Comment: it got rid of the error message but nothing is happening , when i switched to  `./worker.js`